# Use of local dependency in develop mode in a project mounted in a docker container

Tags: docker, python-poetry

I've been facing an issue with which I need some help.

We're working on a project that is dockerized and runs on a docker-compose stack. Our code is mounted in the container to allow live-reload of changes. But this project uses a proprietary library that may require changes. The goal would be to have this library mounted in the container as well since the only way currently is to install it with `poetry add ../ArcheologCommon` and run everything locally (without docker). This is a real pain since we have many configurations and 7+ services to run

The first solution I've found was to mount my local venv into the container but that doesn't work for multiple reasons:

- Mounting the entire venv results in hardcoded absolute paths in the `env/bin/activate` folder that is usable only by the host.
- Mount only the `venv/lib` folder to avoid this hardcoded path issue.

This works very well until I run the `poetry add ../ArcheologCommon`, which gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'archeolog_common'` exception in my container.

Looking around in what poetry did in my venv, I find that my library became an `*.egg-link` file containing the absolute path of my library on my laptop

```sh
~/ ➤ docker exec -ti backend bash
www-data@467190e2f634:~/backend$ cat .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/archeolog-common.egg-link 
/home/path/to/ArcheologCommon
```

The only workaround I found is to mount my local copy of the code directly into the site-packages of the venv, in place of the code already present there:

```yaml
services:
  backend:
     command: server.py --bind 0.0.0.0 --port 9000 --reload-dir /var/www/backend --reload-dir /opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/archeolog_common
    #  [ ...]
     volumes:
       - ...
       - ../../ArcheologCommon/archeolog_common:/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/archeolog_common:ro
```

Which results in changes properly detected and working just fine.

```
WARNING:  StatReload detected file change in '/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/archeolog_common/models/graph.py'. Reloading...
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Finished server process [156]
INFO:     Started server process [191]
```

I think this is a terrible solution (which works, so I still give it credits) but I wonder if there are any better solutions?

PS: I've found similar issues on SO about this, but none of them were about using everything in Docker containers, which is my main requirement since it's a huge hassle to work outside of our docker-compose stack.

Thanks for reading me!

Comment: does building docker image with python sources in virtual environment and dependencies including the 3rd party library resolve the issue?